# Usage of double plural

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

Here we have the plural in the end:

"communication technology services"

Here we have two plurals(quite common in google):

"communications technology services"

Eventually, we could have three plurals =)

"communications technologies services"

When should we use more than one plural to describe this?

Comment: we may also have 'communication technologies service'

Comment: As a rule of thumb, 'when 70+% of the articles on Google do'. "Communication technology services" and "Communications technology services" seem the front runners (and in that order). None is incorrect; if you want to stress the plurality of any aspect, you're free to do so.

Comment: They are all all right. Each has its own meaning, and is to be used according to context. Generally though, it is "communications technology services" with good reason.

Comment: And in this context, isn't 'communications' a subject [like Maths, Physics or Economics] rather than a plural?

Answer (score 10):

As a general rule (and not just in English), when a word or phrase is used as a close modifier in a complex noun phrase, it is stripped of its grammatical endings. (In German, for example the whole phrase is usually written as a single word, and only the last takes any grammatical endings). The way this appears in English is that *usually* a noun used to modify a noun stays in the singular, so

> communication technology services

would be the 'unmarked' or basic form.

However there are plenty of examples of using plural modifiers, to particular emphasis. So *technologies services* would be emphasising that the service related to several different technologies, and furthermore indicating that by *technology* we mean something that may be pluralised: *a technology* in the sense of a particular collection of approaches and methods. *Technology services* would not be specific about whether it had this meaning or not, but I think would tend to imply that we are using *technology* in a more general, (uncountable) sense of "current equipment and how to use it" or something like that.

*Communications* is a bit harder, because that (in the plural form) is often used as the name of a field, like *physics*, and when used in that way, is usually singular. I think *communications techology* is much more likely than *communication technology*.

Comment: "Communications technology services" is a compound noun whose first noun is itself compound.  The structure is [ [communications technology] services ], where I've put brackets around the two compounds.  Stress tells the tale -- it is, or at least can be, 1 2 3.  There are no modifiers in the grammatical sense.

Comment: I accept that my terminology was a bit off - I couldn't think of what you call the first element in a ordinary headed compound noun. I don't think that affects my answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that "communication" is a noncount noun, it is unnecessary to add a plural "s" ending in any situation. That does not mean the "s" won't be added, as we know language is always changing.

"Technology" is also a noncount noun.

"Communication Technology Services" makes the most grammatical sense.